# How to return multiple inner hits in multiple nested sub-queries for the same path?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I have multiple nested sub-queries for the same path, it seems the result will only include the inner hits result of the last nested sub-query. Is there a way to return all of the inner hits results for the multiple nested sub-queries?

e.g.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool: {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {...},
                    "path": "path_a",
                    "inner_hits": {}
                }
            },{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {...},
                    "path": "path_a",
                    "inner_hits": {}
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a unique `name` to your `inner_hits`, then the result will basically contain a map of your inner hits as you're expecting.

*Note*: It seems that sometimes the inner hits contains extra query names (from the other nested queries) in the `matched_queries`, so it may need some post-processing

Answer (score 1):

For the same path one needs to specify the nested path before its sub-queries.

Below is an example of searching, either via the match or the range, in the same nested path. You could modify the search according to your needs.

```
    GET index/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": “path.subpath”,
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { “path.subpath.match1”: “valueMatch” }},
                { "range" : {  “path.subpath.range1” :         {"gte": “rangeMatch”  }  }  
 }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info. But this question is more about having multiple nested queries and it seems the position of the "path" whether before or after the "query" does not resolve the issue.

Comment: My bad, as I assumed it to be multiple nested queries in the same path! Good you got the right solution.