# Multiple Elasticsearch Inner_hits queries are not giving results as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve child document content using inner hits feature of Elastic search. My query contains two has_child clauses as shown in the code snippet below. What I have observed is that I get only those child contents in the inner hit response that are part of second child clauses. It looks like the last inner hits overwrite first inner hits.

Is there any way to get both inner hits?

Here is the query I used.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[

            {  
               "has_child":{  
                  "type":"subformcontent",
                  "query":{
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term":{  
                                    "txt_1.raw":"Malayalam"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term":{  
                                    "parent_field_id":"1000"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }                                            
                  },
               "inner_hits":{  
                     "size":10
                  }                  
               }
            }, 
            {  
               "has_child":{  
                  "type":"subformcontent",
                  "query":{
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term":{  
                                    "txt_1.raw":"Malayalam"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term":{  
                                    "parent_field_id":"1001"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }                                            
                  },
               "inner_hits":{  
                     "size":10
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the mapping of your index? I once had the exact same problem and could try to find the solution again.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html says

> name
>
> The name to be used for the particular inner hit definition in the response. Useful when multiple inner hits have been defined in a single search request. The default depends in which query the inner hit is defined. For has_child query and filter this is the child type, has_parent query and filter this is the parent type and the nested query and filter this is the nested path.

I would guess since you didn't define a name and the documentation says the default value is the **type** for has_child then you can just define names for your inner_hits queries. Otherwise both are named "subformcontent" and consequently they override each other.

```
{  
   "has_child":{  
      ...
      "inner_hits":{  
         "size":10,
         "name": "hits_1"
      }                  
   }
}, 
{  
   "has_child":{  
      ...
      "inner_hits":{  
         "size":10,
         "name": "hits_2"
      }
   }
}
```

Potential duplicate: [How to return multiple inner hits in multiple nested sub-queries for the same path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434155/how-to-return-multiple-inner-hits-in-multiple-nested-sub-queries-for-the-same-pa)

Comment: Thanks Kosi. This solutions worked for me. I am thinking more complicated one. Since this just (1 AND 2) condition what I am thinking is more like (1 AND 2) OR (1 AND 3). I hope I will result on this query as welll. Let me try.

Comment: The above condition is  (1 AND 2) OR (1 AND 3). is also working if we rename the 1 in second enclosed bracket to  other unique name like 4. So the condition should be (1 AND 2) OR (4 ND 3). Basically innerhit name should be unique always.